# Modificar todos los elementos de una lista dentro de una lista con un bucle for sin perder las modificaciones

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, bucle-for, str-replace

```py
info_list = [['Tomás', 'Kyara Gomez', 'Camila'], ['caminar', 'saltar'], ['en la montaña', 'en el parque amplio y naranja por el otoño'], ['2022_-_12_-_29(12:33 am)_--_2023_-_01_-_25(19:13 pm)', '2023_-_02_-_05(00:00 am)']]

#become to datetime format
for i in info_list[3]:
    i = i.replace("_-_", "-").replace("(", " ").replace(")", "")
    print(repr(i)) #imprime cada una de las modificaciones

print(repr(info_list)) #imprimo lista ya con las modificaciones
```

Porque las modificaciones de una lista de listas no se guardan impidiendo obtener la lista de listas final con los elementos de una de las sub-listas ya modificados?

Esta sería la lista obtenida como output correcto:

```
'2022-12-29 12:33 am_--_2023-01-25 19:13 pm'
'2023-02-05 00:00 am'

[['Tomás', 'Kyara Gomez', 'Camila'], ['caminar', 'saltar'], ['en la montaña', 'en el parque amplio y naranja por el otoño'], ['2022-12-29 12:33 am_--_2023-01-25 19:13 pm', '2023-02-05 00:00 am']]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te ocurre porque dentro del bucle la variable `i` es una referencia al elemento que estás procesando, pero al hacerle una asignación `i=` simplemente haces que esa referencia apunte al resultado, sin variar realmente el valor al que apuntaba previamente (el que estaba en la lista).

Es decir, lo que ocurre en tu bucle es equivalente a esto:

```
cadena_original = "hola"
i = cadena_original      # Algo como esto ocurre en cada iteración del bucle
i = i.replace("a", "o")  # y esto es lo que tú haces dentro
```

Y eso obviamente no modificará `cadena_original`.

Este es uno de los raros casos en los que no conviene iterar por los valores, sino por los índices. De ese modo en vez de asignar `i = otra cosa` harás `lista[i] = otra_cosa`, lo cual sí modificará el elemento de la lista.

Es decir:

```
info_list = [['Tomás', 'Kyara Gomez', 'Camila'], ['caminar', 'saltar'], ['en la montaña', 'en el parque amplio y naranja por el otoño'], ['2022_-_12_-_29(12:33 am)_--_2023_-_01_-_25(19:13 pm)', '2023_-_02_-_05(00:00 am)']]
lista = info_list[3]
for i in range(len(lista)):
    lista[i] = lista[i].replace("_-_", "-").replace("(", " ").replace(")", "")

print(repr(info_list)) #imprimo lista ya con las modificaciones
```

y ahora el resultado sí es el deseado:

```
[['Tomás', 'Kyara Gomez', 'Camila'],
 ['caminar', 'saltar'],
 ['en la montaña', 'en el parque amplio y naranja por el otoño'],
 ['2022-12-29 12:33 am_--_2023-01-25 19:13 pm', '2023-02-05 00:00 am']]
```

### Bonus

Otra forma más pythónica es usar la función `enumerate(lista)` que en cada iteración te devuelve una pareja (indice, valor). Así puedes usar el índice para el lado izquierdo de la asignación y el valor para el derecho:

```
for indice, valor in enumerate(lista):
    lista[indice] = valor.replace("_-_", "-").replace("(", " ").replace(")", "")
```

Answer (score 3):

En `for i in info_list[3]:`, `i` es una copia de cada elemento de la lista. El contenido no se copia; simplemente `i` e `info_list[3][0]` hacen referencia al mismo objeto string en memoria.

Sin embargo, cuando haces

```
i = i.replace("_-_", "-").replace("(", " ").replace(")", "")
```

estás **reemplazando** el contenido de `i`, que es una variable semánticamente separada de `info_list[3][0]`. Por tanto, Python crea un nuevo objeto string donde poner la nueva cadena que generas, y reemplaza la referencia en `i`, manteniendo la otra intacta. El resultado es que hay dos cadenas, una dentro del `for`, la otra en la lista.

**Solución**

Cuando deseas procesar listas modificandolas, lo aconsejable es partir con una lista vacia donde ir colocando los elementos modificados. Al terminar de agregar, reemplazas la lista original.

Esto no consuma mucha memoria. Los objetos mismos no se copian; la nueva lista es sólo una lista de referencias a esos objetos.

Adaptando tu código a este principio, queda así:

```
info_list = [['Tomás', 'Kyara Gomez', 'Camila'], ['caminar', 'saltar'], ['en la montaña', 'en el parque amplio y naranja por el otoño'], ['2022_-_12_-_29(12:33 am)_--_2023_-_01_-_25(19:13 pm)', '2023_-_02_-_05(00:00 am)']]

#become to datetime format
lista = []
for i in info_list[3]:
    i = i.replace("_-_", "-").replace("(", " ").replace(")", "")
    lista.append(i)
    print(repr(i)) #imprime cada una de las modificaciones

print(repr(info_list))
info_list[3] = lista
print(repr(info_list)) #imprimo lista ya con las modificaciones
```

produce:

```
'2022-12-29 12:33 am_--_2023-01-25 19:13 pm'
'2023-02-05 00:00 am'
[['Tomás', 'Kyara Gomez', 'Camila'], ['caminar', 'saltar'], ['en la montaña', 'en el parque amplio y naranja por el otoño'], ['2022_-_12_-_29(12:33 am)_--_2023_-_01_-_25(19:13 pm)', '2023_-_02_-_05(00:00 am)']]
[['Tomás', 'Kyara Gomez', 'Camila'], ['caminar', 'saltar'], ['en la montaña', 'en el parque amplio y naranja por el otoño'], ['2022-12-29 12:33 am_--_2023-01-25 19:13 pm', '2023-02-05 00:00 am']]
```